# Where has or has within different database connection doesn't work, whats the alternative to query the related model (in a cross database connection)?

Tags: laravel

I tried by getting the collection and work with collection but the problem is that I need pagination to work because the collection is 70k items. and paginate returns a 'LengthAwarePaginator'

```
 Order::has('orderTracking')->with(['orderTracking', 'orderTracking.shippingCosts'])
        ->shipped()
        ->orderBy('id_order', 'desc')
        ->paginate(200);
```

the has method doesn't work because the related model is in other database connection. as far I understood laravel doesn't support that.

any ideas how can filter the paginated and paginate. or what is the correct approach?

Comment: If `orderTracking` is on the same physical server then you can use `dbname.orderTracking` as the table name in the related model instead of using a different connection. However this may not work on many to many relationships and will definitely not work across multiple database instances

Comment: so how can I proceed?

Comment: what is shipped function? is that your relation model?

Comment: Which case is it? Is it a different database instance? If so I think the best approach is to migrate to the same database

Comment: is a db in other network

Comment: return $paginator->setCollection($filtered);

I did this, although is not what I wanted. however I have first page empty collection. any ideas how to re-paginate ?